# Try-catch creating new array in C# - where to initialize it?

Tags: c#, try-catch

If I'm reading a string from a config file, I'd use a similar approach to the below, in case the string isn't present in the file being read and an exception results.  However, if I want to do the same for a string[] array, I can't just 'new it up' outside the try block because the size is not known.

I can't new it up in the try block itself.  How should it be approached?

```
string[] logContent; // can't new it up here as don't know the size

                try
                {
                    logContent = File.ReadAllLines(aLogFile);
                }
                catch
                {
                    throw new Exception("LoggerStandard: Specified Logfile exists but could not be read.");
                }
```

Comment: Why would you want to "new it up"?

Comment: Why would people downvote this with no comment?  Goons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could initialize it to a default value:

```
string[] logContent = null; 
try
{
    logContent = File.ReadAllLines(aLogFile);
}
catch
{
    // Be careful with the error message here => there might be other reasons
    // that the ReadAllLines threw an exception
    throw new Exception("LoggerStandard: Specified Logfile exists but could not be read.");
}
```

Comment: +1 for the caution on the catch.  Perhaps catch specific exceptions (in the right order) and then have a general catch last?

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize it with `null` and then check against it.

Answer (score 0):

By default it is null. You can leave it as is, if this is appropriate for your program, or initialize to any array according to your needs. Anyway, successful initialization inside of try block overrides this.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] logContent=null;
try
{
     logContent = File.ReadAllLines(aLogFile);                 
}                 
catch                 
{                     
  throw new Exception("LoggerStandard: Specified Logfile exists but could not be read.");                 
}
```